# test code changes on triggers SQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql-server, oracle, triggers

Hello I am developing a c++ client that create triggers on mysql, sql-server, sqlite and oracle. The query for create the triggers is part of the application. The thing is that i need my app, at the start, check any modification of the code between the code in the app and the code in the database. In that case the app delete the database trigger and execute the query to create the new trigger. I can not just delete and create a trigger at any starting because database is constantly used for clients. Any Ideas. I know every database has its own characteristics but i cannot find a solution.

Comment: what is the business case for dropping and creating triggers on the fly from the application?  why do you need to do this?

Comment: "I can not just delete and create a trigger at any starting because database is constantly used for clients" - apparently you can, because you just described a scenario where you *want to do just that*. It seems the only added criteria is avoid that unless you determine you *have to*

Comment: Dropping and creating triggers case it is just for clarify the solution. If there will be several operators using same database, one operator may drop the trigger by the time other is using the table where the trigger is attached.

Comment: The app is a client constantly used by operators. The use the same version of the app. Let say On day X, every one start using the new version of the code on his/her PC. If there is a new version of the trigger query its not viable that every client of the operator drop and create a trigger, mostly because other operator should already using database. the correct behavior is that the first client connecting database check trigger on database and it will be the one dropping and creating. The others clients simply will not note modifications between its inner trigger and database's trigger.

Comment: Resuming i need a query checking for modifications between the app trigger and the triggers on database. it can be by any mean. A solution will be modified one field on the table of the database where the trigger is inserted, example for recording the version of the trigger. in this case app read the field and compare with the internal version of the trigger. The problem is that table sys (sql server) cannot be modified by hand. Am I wrong?

Comment: It appears that you may have a misunderstanding of triggers. Each client does not have his own version of a trigger. The same trigger is shared by all users. When you change a trigger you don't have to change your application - you change the code compiled in the database and the new version of the trigger is now in use by everyone using the database, regardless of whether they attached before or after the new version of the trigger was compiled. Also - each database engine has different ways of implementing triggers - there is no commonality. Best of luck.

Comment: When i meant the trigger of the client I was referring to the query within the client that create the trigger on database. The trigger on database is created only by the client itself. There is no trigger on the app, only a query that create a trigger every time it verified changes on the trigger on database and the trigger that will be created by the app.

Comment: problem is that the client is updated very often. In case the update include a modification of the "trigger on the client", then the client itself must drop and create a new trigger on the database.